# Tiling of polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a polygon (possibly nonconvex, but not intersecting itself) with all the sides parallel to one of the axes.

I am interested on whether $X$ can be tiled by (finitely many) squares.

For example, if all the sides of $X$ have rational sides, then it can be tiled by squares. On the other hand, it is known that every rectangle that can be tiled by squares must has that its ratio of height/width is rational.

My question is, what are the known obstacles for $X$ to have a tiling by squares?

Comment: You might look at small configurations of few squares with rational sides and one or two squares with commensurable but irrational sides (and maybe having instead two squares with irrational and incommensurable  sides) to see what you can form. Tiling rectangles with squares leads to systems of linear equations with integral coefficients; perhaps this study will be enhanced by the theory of such systems for rectangles.  Gerhard "Old Tools For New Constructions" Paseman, 2017.07.10.

Comment: In particular, looking at differences of two sets, where each set is a (not necessarily disjoint) union of axis-aligned squares, and finding efficient ways to represent this difference is or should be a problem in computational geometry literature.  Gerhard "Think Of Pixar Before Pixar" Paseman, 2017.07.10.